# Did Omar Khayyam say this about religion?

Tags: quotes, religion, islam, iran

[Atheistrepublic.com](http://www.atheistrepublic.com/gallery/omar-khayyam-if-logic-occupied-place-faith-superstition) made the following meme which claims:

[image]

> lf instead of studying religion, men would have
>   devoted to develop mathematics - algebra.
>
> lf logic of science would have occupied the
>   place of Sufism, faith and superstition.
>
> Religion that divides human beings would
>   have replaced by humanism...

The same meme was reposted on [EOHT.info](http://www.eoht.info/page/Omar+Khayyam). [Mukto-mona.com](https://mukto-mona.com/new_site/mukto-mona/Articles/ajoy/scientific_mind.htm) claims the quote is from one of his Arabic poems but doesn't give any citation.

Comment: These phrases don't even make sense, I'll try to find the Persian origins. If they exist, we should be able to get a source.

Comment: @daraos I'm going to go with bad translation. Or just bad English if its fake.

Comment: @fredsbend I know, I'm looking for other translations now.

Comment: While searching for keywords, unsuccessfully so far, I started to wonder why I'm doing it. I learn something interesting in the process, sure, but I don't see why anyone should spent time searching for a source if the person who makes the claim didn't bother. I can make up such quotes right now within a few minutes and it would be my job to provide a source. "random guy on the Internet said X" is not a reputable claim.

Comment: If a claim shared by 95 and liked by 426 people is not notable, then what is notable?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin It's very notable, but you should use more-convincing sources to show the notability. http://www.atheistrepublic.com/gallery/omar-khayyam-if-logic-occupied-place-faith-superstition ; http://www.eoht.info/page/Omar+Khayyam ;

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin a much longer version of the supposed quote is here: http://www.arabhumanists.org/humanism/arab-humanist-quotes/

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin This 11 April 2005 article by Alamgir Hossain is the oldest version of the claim I can find so far: http://www.islam-watch.org/m-hussain/myth_islams_contribution.htm

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin don't you think that 426 people is a very small amount? This is less than 0.001% of the population of Iran. And also people just liked the words, they have not expressed belief that this is correct. I agree with Daraos: it is trivial to create hundreds of them in few seconds. Or as **Omar Khayyam wrote in 1121 "The problem with internet quotes is that you can't always depend on their accuracy"**

Comment: @DavePhD The article cites a lot of things without any citation.

Comment: Atheist Universe says the quote is from his poem rubaiyat. http://atheistuniverse.net/profiles/blogs/the-so-called-islamic-golden-age-was-it-really-islamic

Comment: Wiki entry of the poem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubaiyat_of_Omar_Khayyam

Comment: Found the poem Rubaiyat: https://archive.org/stream/TheRubaiyatOfOmarKhayyam-FirstVersion-Illustrated/TheRubaiyatOfOmarKhayyam-FirstVersion-Illustrated_djvu.txt

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I was looking at the archive-dot-org document yesterday, but couldn't find anything similar to the quote. I searched the OCR text by keywords.

Comment: It's definitely **not** from the Rubaiyat. [Even the quatrains unpublished by Fitzgerald](https://archive.org/details/quatrainsofomark00omar) don't discuss algebra, which couldn't be worded any differently in any translation. It's also not four lines long.

Comment: It's not in any of the Arabic poems translated in *The Wine of Wisdom*, but it only has about half of the 25 that are claimed to exist. The rest might not be available in English translation; most scholars who deal with Khayyam don't bother with the Arabic poems at all.

Comment: Khayyam is claimed to have written a lot of stuff, not all of it well-authenticated, and what is authenticated not always well-translated.  It would be essentially impossible to prove that he did not write a given piece, though if one could identify the source then it would be possible to demonstrate a poor or misleading translation.